# So I need some help as to why this code fails SubStringAfter/ toIntOrNull() produces a null Why?

Tags: string, kotlin, google-sheets-api

I know this is going to end up with me smacking my head but I don't understand why this does not worked as expected. Basically I am calling a google Sheet Append method getting the result and saving the last row value.
I have tried these and still the toIntOrNull ends up null but if I use a numeric value (s ="117" it works as expected ! So at this point I'm totally stumped. Using the Android Studio scratch utility

```
    /*This should produce the output of an Integer !
    response from Google Sheets Append 
    "updatedRange":"tData!A117:I117","updatedRows":1}} 
    get the "target"
    var s: String = result.updates.updatedRange.substringAfter("I")
    this returns "117" as expected  
   
    testing !  */
    var s = "tData!A117:I117"
    s = s.substringAfter("I")
    // again result is 117 with a length of 3   
    //  .trimStart("I"
    var lr = s.toIntOrNull()
    println ("$s  $lr") // 117 null Why ?
```

Comment: As provided, your code looks okay, and [runs as expected in Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/FmOkZwz71).

Comment: The code above works fine for me, too. Could your original code have (invisible) characters not in the question above? For example, if the string had a zero-width space or similar anywhere after the `I`, then `toIntOrNull()` would return null.

Comment: Didn't  think of running it in the playground and it works perfect there? more stumped than ever

Comment: Ok just in case someone stumbles across this I solved My issue by adding !! (!! asserts that an expression is non-null.) and it works perfect But I still having a nagging doubt about WHY this would work ? (var lr = s.toIntOrNull()!!